# Why is model._meta.get_fields() returning unexpected relationship column names, and can this be prevented?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, metadata

Imagine I have some models as below:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Medium(models.Model):
    researcher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="medium_researcher")
    old_medium_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Uptake(models.Model):
    material_quality = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    medium = models.ForeignKey(Medium, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="uptake_medium")
```

Now I have a function to return all column names to generate some overview in my HTML as such:

```
from database.models import Medium
MODEL_HEADERS=[f.name for f in Medium._meta.get_fields()]
MODEL_HEADERS
['uptake_medium', 'id', 'researcher', 'old_medium_name']
```

Why does this return `uptake_medium`? As this is a ForeignKey relation set within the `Uptake` model, it should only be present within the `Uptake` model right? When I review the admin models this column does not show up, neither in the db.sqlite3 model when checking `Uptake`, so it seems to be sort of hidden, and only show up when requested with `_meta`. The relationship seems to be correct... This is causing a lot of problems with my code, and it would be great if only the 'non-meta' columns only could be returned. How should I approach?

Comment: Because you can query with `my_medium.uptake_medium.all()`. That is the idea of a `related_name`: to query the relation in reverse.

Comment: I do see that from ```Medium._meta.get_fields()``` the ```uptake_medium``` is classified as ```<ManyToOneRel: database.uptake>```, perhaps I can try to exclude based on ManyToOneRel status.

Comment: Every ```Uptake``` can have a single ```Medium```, but a ```Medium``` can be used in many different ```Uptakes```. Hence I think my relationship is set right? Then every ```Uptake``` is populated with a ```Medium ID``` column referring to the Medium of relevance. Why would there be a column added to ```Medium``` referring to ```Uptakes```? Does every row in this ```Medium``` column have a list or something referring to all ```Uptakes``` in case I would like to query?

Comment: no, but a model field and a database column are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this return uptake_medium? As this is a `ForeignKey` relation set within the `Uptake` model, it should only be present within the `Uptake` model right?

You can access the relation in reverse, for example:

```
my_medium.uptake_medium.all()
```

to obtain all `Update`s related to the `Medium` instance named `medium`.

You can also filter on that field, for example:

```
Medium.objects.filter(uptake_medium__material_quantity=42)
```

hence it is accessible just like any field.

You can filter with:

```
from django.db.models.fields.reverse_related import ManyToOneRel

[f.name for f in Medium._meta.get_fields() if not isinstance(f, ManyToOneRel)]
```

Comment: Thank you, ```TypeError: isinstance expected 2 arguments, got 1```, but from here I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: This works: ```MODEL_HEADERS=[f.name for f in Medium._meta.get_fields() if not isinstance(f , ManyToOneRel)]```